# Запоминание текущего состояния компонентов (для таймера)

Tags: c++builder, c++

Возможно ли в C++ Builder 2010? Поясню: есть, допустим, StringGrid1 с двумя строками, вторая пустая. Есть StringGrid2, допустим, тоже с двумя строками, вторая пустая, есть ValueListEditor - тоже пустой.

Теперь - есть таймер, который через каждую секунду принимает данные с сервера, и раскидывает их по этим компонентам. Если тупо в таймер вогнать прием с сервера, то выйдет фигня. Надо, что бы компоненты, так сказать, стирали из себя предыдущие поступившие данные, и вписывали новые.

Или может есть более простое решение?

p.s. И так, что бы скроллы не шалили)

Comment: Почти у всех компонентов есть свойство clear: stringgrid1.clear и тд.

Comment: у StringGrid нету такого свойства.

Comment: Случайно отредактировал. Вопрос можно закрыть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У строк и столбцов StringGrid есть метод Clear, который их очищает. Очистка компонента

```
var i, j: Integer;
begin
  with StringGRid1 do
    for i := 0 to RowCount - 1 do
      begin
        Rows[i].Clear;
      end;
end;
```

Если нужно не трогать заголовки, то пробегать индексы, начиная с 1.

Comment: Это для делфи. Хотя перевести для билдера не трудно, помогло, спасибо.